# Grading Calculator Equation for lesser grades

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator, equation

I'm trying to create a calculator that when you input your points, and the total amount of points in the class you receive a lot of information about it, I currently have working the letter grade, percentage, and the amount of points that you need to get to the next grade up.
Ex. 95/100

A 95%

Points Needed = 5

I want to do the same thing with Points needed but opposite. So with the same example it would be

Points Lost = 5

I currently have the script for my current Points Needed if it helps, but I really can't figure out the equation for this, luckily not necessary for a school project, just for a solo project so I can learn how to code.

Here is the code for the Points Needed

```
        var pointsNeeded = totalGrade.value - grade.value; 
            if (gradePercentage > 100) {
                pointsNeeded = pointsNeeded * -1; 
                document.getElementById("pointsNeeded").innerHTML = "You can lose " + pointsNeeded + " point(s) and still have 100%"; 
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("pointsNeeded").innerHTML = pointsNeeded; 
            }
    }
    else if (gradePercentage < 89, gradePercentage > 79) {
        var pointsNeeded = Math.round(10 * ((totalGrade.value * 0.9) -               
        grade.value)) / 10; 
        document.getElementById("pointsNeeded").innerHTML = pointsNeeded; 
    }
    else if (gradePercentage < 79, gradePercentage > 69) {
        var pointsNeeded = Math.round(10 * ((totalGrade.value * 0.8) -               
        grade.value)) / 10; 
        document.getElementById("pointsNeeded").innerHTML = pointsNeeded; 
    }
    else if (gradePercentage < 69, gradePercentage > 59) {
        var pointsNeeded = Math.round(10 * ((totalGrade.value * 0.7) -               
        grade.value)) / 10; 
        document.getElementById("pointsNeeded").innerHTML = pointsNeeded; 
    }
    else if (gradePercentage < 59) {
        var pointsNeeded = Math.round(10 * ((totalGrade.value * 0.6) -              
        grade.value)) / 10; 
        document.getElementById("pointsNeeded").innerHTML = pointsNeeded; 
    }
```

gradePercentage being the actual percentage, totalGrade being the full grade, and grade being the grade you have.

Also these are the grade values,

```
        var gradeLetter = "A"
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradeLetter +                    " " + result + "%";          
    }
    if (gradePercentage > 79.9, gradePercentage < 90) {
        var gradeLetter = "B"
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradeLetter +                    " " + result + "%";
    }
    if (gradePercentage > 69.9, gradePercentage < 80) {
        var gradeLetter = "C"
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradeLetter +                    " " + result + "%";
    }
    if (gradePercentage > 59.9, gradePercentage < 70) {
        var gradeLetter = "D"
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradeLetter +                    " " + result + "%";          
    }
    if (gradePercentage < 59.9) {
        var gradeLetter = "F"
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = gradeLetter +                    " " + result + "%";  
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "next grade up". Exactly what numeric values constitute an A, B, C, etc? Are you considering variations like A+, A, and A-, or just A?

Comment: If C > 69 and D < 60, what grade is 61-68?

Comment: Sorry I edited it

Comment: Here I'll edit my main post to have these equations.

Comment: So, given a `gradePercentage` (e.g. 78 = C), you want to know how many points you would need to subtract to bring it down to the next lowest grade (D)?

Comment: Yes exactly, I cant think of the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is pretty self-explanatory:

```
let startingPoints = 952.3 // How many points you got on the test
let maxPoints = 1049 // Max possible points you could have gotten

// Your grade (0-100%):
let gradePercentage = 100 * startingPoints / maxPoints; // E.g. 90.7816968541468

// How much less you'd need (as a percentage) to get the next lowest grade:

let extraPercentage = ( gradePercentage % 10 ) + 0.01; // E.g. 0.7916968541468015

// Your new grade (as a percentage) if you bumped it down:
let newGrade = gradePercentage - extraPercentage; // E.g. 89.99

// How many points you'd have to reduce your score by to bump it down to the next lowest 
let extraPoints = ( extraPercentage / 100 * maxPoints ) // E.g. 8.304899999999947

// What your score would be if you bumped it down to the next level:
let newExtraPoints = startingPoints - extraPoints; // E.g. 943.9951

console.log( `Your grade is ${gradePercentage}% (${startingPoints} points out of a possible ${maxPoints}). If you subtract ${extraPercentage}% (or ${extraPoints} points), your grade will be ${newGrade}% (${newExtraPoints} points)` );
```

The only trickiness is that we're adding 0.01, which technically could be 0.001, or 0.0001, or...well, we have to add *something* to drop below the limit, and with no set "right" amount, I'm choosing 0.01 because it works out nicely.

Example output:

```
Your grade is 90.7816968541468% (952.3 points out of a possible 1049).
If you subtract 0.7916968541468015% (or 8.304899999999947 points),
your grade will be 89.99% (943.9951 points)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I did it and it worked for your example but for my grade which is 

952.3/1049 about a 91 percent. it gives me that if I subtract about .7 it should bring down my grade but that is false, it is actually about 10 points. So do you know what happened. (I haven't changed anything)

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent If you use `100 * (952.3 / 1049)` as your starting grade (90.7816968541468 to be precise), you get `Your grade is 90.7816968541468. If you subtract 0.7916968541468015, your grade will be 89.99`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Oh yes, is there a way to convert that percentage to points though? I see what the equation did now, and it is what I wanted, just I need the point amount not the percentage.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked, I did have to add a few .values to get it to work, but I used the console to fix that.